# how to install check_inode plugin in nagios

Tags: nagios

i have to install a plugin on a red hat server where nagios is already configured.
the plugin to be installed is inode_checker which i got from this link
[how to install inode checker in nagios](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-and-Systems-Management/check_disk_inodes/details)

but when i opened this link i could find a shell script here.
now i am not sure whether i have to place the shell script directly on the server in the location /usr/local/nagios/libexec/ or is there any other way to do it since the other plugins available in this location seems to be different and i am not able to open them.
what am i doing wrong here?please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a bash script so simply download and place it in the folder where you have other scripts sitting. Make sure to make it executable like

```
chmod +x scriptname
```

Then you should be able to use it in nagios by creating a Command object. You can find the location of the folder where your scripts are located by looking at the resources.cfg file which should hold something like below:

```
 $USER1$=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins
```

Hope this helps.